# AplicarEfeito de transição ao alterar a source de um controlo Image

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um botão ao qual está associada uma imagem carregada a partir de um ResourceDictionary.
No XAML carrego-as assim:

```
<Button x:Name="selecao" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10" Click="selecao_Click">
    <Image x:Name="img" Source = "{StaticResource inverno}"/>
</Button>
```

No code-behind altero-a assim:

```
private void mudarImagem(int i)
{
    switch (currentImage)
    {
        case 0: img.Source = (BitmapImage)Application.Current.Resources["inverno"]; break;
        case 1: img.Source = (BitmapImage)Application.Current.Resources["primavera"]; break;
        case 2: img.Source = (BitmapImage)Application.Current.Resources["verao"]; break;
        case 3: img.Source = (BitmapImage)Application.Current.Resources["outono"]; break;
    }
}
```

É possível aplicar um efeito de transição, do tipo "slide" ao passar de uma imagem para a outra?

Answer (score 0):

Tens sim como fazer isso, mas é um pouco chato.

1º Forma: esta é a mais fácil e simples

Você pode criar de parte uma imagem do formato .gif, isto é com todas outras imagens que pretendes que sejam visualizado no slide, e por fim anexar dentro do c# (pirtubox,painel,form ...etc)

2º Forma: esta é fácil mas um pouco extenso

Define um tempo para cada imagem ao executarl, para isso terás que usar o "Timer"

ex:

```
private void mudarImagem(int i)
{
    switch (currentImage)
    {
//Declaração de variáveis junto com a labelque vai receber a contagem  
     int Tempo1, Tempo2 = Convert.ToInt32(lbContagem.Text);

            Tempo1 = Tempo2 + 1; //Inicialização da contagem
            lbContagem.Text = Convert.ToString(Tempo1); //Label que esta a receber a contagem

            if (Tempo1 == 1)
            {
                 img.Source =BitmapImage.Current.Resources["inverno"]
            }
            if (Tempo1 == 3)
            {
                 img.Source =BitmapImage.Current.Resources["primavera"]; break;
            }
            if (Tempo1 == 5)
            {
                 img.Source =BitmapImage.Application.Current.Resources["verao"];
            }
            if (Tempo1 == 7)
            {
                img.Source =BitmapImage.Application.Current.Resources["outono"]; 
            }
                timer1.Enabled = false;
              return;
            }
}
```

testa se não der certo apaga os "BitmapImage".

Comment: Não sei se me expliquei bem!

Comment: Eu sei mudar a imagem ... mas quero que ela surja com efeitos de transição.